# How To Delete A Large Video File From iOS Device Which Does Not Show Up in Photos?

Tags: ios, video, macos

I have a large video (18GB) on my iPad that I deleted, but somehow did not actually get deleted off the device.  It is not visible on the iPad itself but I can see it through any iOS file browser (iMazing, IBrowse, IExplorer)... just can't seem to delete it with these.

It shows as 'Other' space being taken up, and I cannot update the device now, because is is full.  I could restore the device to factory, but I don't want to lose all my other apps.  Restoring from backup now would just give me the offending file back, I believe.

How to rid myself of this file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Photos app, select the Albums view and you'll see a Recently Deleted album there. Deleting the video from there will free the space for you. If you're not hurting for space, you can leave them and they'll be cleared from the device after 30 days. Each photo/video in the album is shown with the remaining countdown before the media is permanently removed by the OS.

Comment: Cheers, Marcus!